# Objective C: Check if int exists, including zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm dealing with the addressbook, and I want to check if their is an ID set for the contact being created. However, the address book ID is an integer, which I'm worried might be zero based. So I want to do something like...

```
if (_contact.id) { ... }
```

But with this I run the risk of it assuming the contact with the id 0 doesn't exist, even though it does. This is a difficult problem to test since it would involve setting up a new address book.

So my question is, is there a way to check if the contact is actually NULL/Nil without it assuming that 0 means it's null? Like an "is integer" function or something to the nature?

Comment: Compare it against `kABRecordInvalidID`.

Comment: Actually, clarify what `_contact` is. Is a `ABPersonRef` or something else?

Comment: It's actually an integer pulled from core data (so NSInteger I believe), which holds the record id from the address book. So I'm doing this to determine if we're editing a contact or if we need to add a new one.

Comment: I asked what `_contact` is, not `_contact.id`. But I guess it's some custom entity. So the better question then is how did you populate the `id` property of your entity?

Comment: So you want to check whether a property has been set?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if it's set. If I have an existing contact then I want to pass the id into a dictionary (where I store all the values for the contact). Otherwise I omit the id, pass the other values. I populate the id property of my entity with the `NSNumber *recordID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ABRecordGetRecordID(ref)];` and stick it in my contacts entity. But it's worth noting these are being done in completely different controllers.

Comment: I'm probably going to just store it as a string instead of an integer, then convert it back. That way I can just do `if(_contact.id.length)` Feels sloppy but I can't think of a better option. If you come up with one please put it as an answer and I'll accept it later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check whether a property was set.

You can add another `@property (readonly, getter=isIdSet) BOOL idSet` and set the backing iVar in the setter for `id`:

```
- (void)setId:(int)id {
    _id = id;
    _idSet = YES;
}
```

Then just check `if (contact.idSet)`

Alternatively you could use an `NSNumber` object and check if the property is `nil`.